# How do i create struccture of a structure of a structure, ect. nesting multiple structures?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, nested

I'm having problem figuring out how should i implement nesting of multiple structures, the goal is to have depot, which has warehouses, which has racks with shelves and shelves have place for items and their 2 digit id. Right now i have code looking like this:

```
#include<iostream>
struct place{
    unsigned short place_[65545][2];
};
struct shelf{
    place shelf_[128];
};
struct rack{
    shelf rack_[128];
};
struct warehouse{
    rack warehouse_[128];
    shelf handy_warehouse_shelf_;
};
struct depot{
    warehouse depot_[128];
    rack handy_rack_;
    shelf handy_depot_shelf_;
};
int main(){
    depot name1;
    name1.depot_[0].warehouse_[0].rack_[0].shelf_[0].place_[0][0]=1;
    return 0; 
}
```

And can't figure out if it's my problem with understanding how structures work or how i access specific "cell" in nested array.

Comment: Local variables are usually stored on the stack, which is limited; On Windows is usually only a single MiB, on Linux it's typically 8 MiB. Now calculate the size of your `depot` structure and see if you can fit all that data inside the stack.

Comment: And while I guess my comment above is the problem you're having, you don't actually say what it is or even ask a question. So please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It crashes outputing random numbers.

Comment: Have you tried *two* nested structures, before you attempt *seventeen trillion?*

Comment: One depot is 70.39 terabytes large.

Comment: The problem isn't in the way the code nests structures; that's all okay. It's the **size** of the resulting object. That's because of a **design** problem. For example, while it's possible that one or two places **might** need to hold 65545 items, almost all of them will have **far fewer**. Same for all the rest. Instead of hard-coding the sizes, you need to create objects that can resize themselves to match the number of elements that they hold. Read about `std::vector`, which is designed for exactly this kind of situation.

Comment: I'd use vector if i could, i can only use <iostream>, is it possible to nest it or create structure in "shape" of a tree?

Answer (score 0):

Your depot is using something over `65545 * 2 * 128 * 128 * 128 * 128 * sizeof(unsigned short)` bytes as memory. This is of course far too much for a typical implementation of automatic storage ("the stack" ... limited to something between 1 and 8 MB usually AFAIK).

The nesting of structures is correct ... there's just to much of it.

I'd advise to change the design to:

```cpp
struct Position {
  unsigned warehouse;
  unsigned rack;
  unsigned shelf;
  unsigned place;
  unsigned row;
  unsigned column;
};

struct Depot {
  std::unordered_map<Position, unsigned short> places;
}
```

The above is of course not a complete implementation, and you also need to think about how you handle things like `handy_depot_shelf` but I hope you get the idea.

Access via

```cpp
the_depot.places[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}] = 1;
```

That's of course only for demonstration purposes; you should hide that in a member function and do things like bounds checks.

---

If you can't use `std::unordered_map` (an assignment?) then you need to implement an alternative for that yourself. A very simple start would be a linked list with key and value in each node. Iterate over the list until you find a node with matching key, then return reference to value. Otherwise add new node with key and value, return reference to that value.

Comment: I assume `std::map` isn't in `iostream` and it's the only thing i'm allowed to use. Is it possible to do list of structures, in this case list of "places" (not necessarily with declared maximum size)?